# How to write trace output to a text file without a web server in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, logging, trace, text-files

I have an application that writes traces with a timestamp when certain items are clicked or accessed. I need to write these to a text log file so that they can be accessed remotely.. The device the app runs on doesn't have a web server and doesn't run the flash debug player, os is xp. How can I send these traces to a text file? I noticed [Arthropod](http://arthropod.stopp.se/) writes to an html file, but I need to do this automatically without interaction.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Air provides a file I/O API via the FileStream class.

You can also use it's embedded SQLite db if you need to store full logs.

Comment: Good ! In that case it would be nice if you could mark this answer as correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe AIR is definitely the way to go, some obscure other possibilities could be:

use Flash 5 and fscommand("save", "file.txt"); [see a post on moock.org](http://www.moock.org/asdg/technotes/fscommandsave/)

or you can store the data in a [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/SharedObject.html#includeExamplesSummary) and try to access the objects on the harddrive.
More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object)

Comment: Thanks Les, yes Adobe Air saved the day

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with my video player.  Here is what I came up with.

I created a static Log class that I use instead of trace.

```
Log.s("[info] Bla.onRemove")
```

Then inside the static s method I push the string into an array and trace the string.  I added a right click option to copy the logs to their clipboard.  Oh your might want to encrypt the logs so the user doesn't see them.

I had doubt about pushing this many items into an array.  But after some profiling and testing I had over 60k items in the array and I didn't see any memory increase so I guess its fairly safe.

My other ideas was to make an AIR app and connect it via LocalConnection but I had some issues getting that connection to work.  Although I have a lot less confidence in the stability of LocalConnections.

If you like this solution and want to see more code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a web host and write a web service that creates a log file or stores it on a database, and call the web service.

Or you could use something like [dropbox](http://dropbox.com) or [syncplicity](http://syncplicity.com) to sync the local text file to their servers or another computer

Comment: The device has no outward access to the internet. The log files are retieved via 3G. I would also still have to create a text file to use dropbox or syncplicity... and that's where I'm stuck....